# Unable To Make Working Bootable USB of 32 GB but It is possible in 16 GB

Tags: system-installation, usb, 16.04, live-usb

I have Sandisk 16 GB and 32 GB Pendrives. I use [Win32DiskImager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) and [UniversalUSBInstaller](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) and [lili](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) etc for each one 16 and 32 GB pen drives. For 16 GB is working successfully but 32 GB it says unable to find a medium containing a live file system. And this is not happening with me but also to my friends having 32 GB USB. Why is this happening and what is the solution?

Comment: It's much easier to make a live USB from an existing Ubuntu install. Do you have access to a Linux box?

Comment: what is linux box. i had tried to read about it but i got nothing understandable

Comment: I recommend using Rufus: https://rufus.akeo.ie/ In some cases it will fix and configure everything for you.

Comment: rufus is crap for linux. It is good for windows

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this method](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)? You also may need to [format the usb drive as bootable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200124(v=ws.11).aspx) first, use `format fs=fat32` To answer your secondary question above, 'Linux box' is a computer with Linux already running